# Public keys and Private keys AES

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, cryptography

I found a [solution](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/encrypt-in-javascript-and-decrypt-in-C-Sharp-with-aes-algorithm/) to what I want to accomplish, but I have some queries too make sure I understand the concept correctly.

**Note: I am still a newbie with Cryptography!**

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('7061737323313233'); 
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('7061737323313233');
```

1. How secure is the key and IV values when they displayed so openly (***as shown above***) in javascript you can view the values from browsers with inspect element or is my understanding of how the solution works wrong?
2. How does the process of exchanging keys between application and service work?

Comment: Maybe you should specify what you are trying to accomplish. However, your questions are valid, and the code on the page you've linked seems to be some kind of demo which is hardly useable in real life. As I see there is no key exchange, both js and server side works with hardcoded AES keys. This is not secure at all, an attacker could get the key from the js and decrypt the sent data. HTTPS was invented for scenarios like this.

Comment: What I want to accomplish is encrypting and decrypting credentials for a login from an html application too C# service like WCF. @Nite

Comment: Using HTTPS is not an option? It does exactly that. If you want your own solution(which maybe isn't a good idea) you can use RSA instead of AES. Theoretically you can include the public key in the js and keep the private on the server.

Comment: Is it possible to randomize the key value on the app sending it as random text and then somehow only be able to read the value on the server while using AES? @Nite

Comment: AES is a symmetric-key algorithm, that means its key must be kept in secret. You absolutely mustn't send the plain AES key on the channel you are trying to secure.

Comment: Ah thank you for clearing that up! I will do a little bit more research on RSA and others alike.. @Nite

Comment: @Nite *Theoretically you can include the public key in the js and keep the private on the server.* **Super bad idea**.  The js script has to be transmitted to the client on their first connect, an attacker could simply replace the public key in the script with their own and decrypt **all** traffic.

Comment: @RGdent If you are using browser Javascript, you **must** use HTTPS, as any cryptography in browser Javascript is vulnerable.  If you aren't using browser Javascript, you should still really use TLS, but if thats not an option, using AES and RSA together is the next best option, but it's not easy to get it right.  You'll need HMACs etc.

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying that. Thats another kind of attack a cryptography newbie should be aware of, "man in the middle". To avoid that, the client should be able to check that the public key is really the server's - and we are again at HTTPS. This is why one should never invent own cryptography, use established standards instead. @Luke Park

Comment: Thank you @LukePark I will take a look into the suggestions you made.